# "Object doesn't support property or method 'getAttribute'"

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I'm working with Dynamics CRM 2011 Online and trying to refactor some code that works on the Quote > Add Product page to also work on Order > Add Product. The problem is that when the page loads I get the error "Unable to get property 'getValue' of undefined or null reference."

I went into the IE console (tried both IE 9 and 10) and typed in what I believed to be the offending line:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute('ati_clin').getValue()
```

It complains with "Object doesn't support property or method 'getAttribute'". I also tried

```
document.getElementById('ati_clin')
```

but that too fails.

This doesn't make sense to me because I can use the HTML view of the developer console to find the object on the page and it's clearly there (no typo too). It also doesn't make sense that this statement fails in the console on both pages even though one of the pages runs properly at runtime and the other doesn't. Shouldn't it at least work on the page that *does* work at runtime?

After doing some research I think the following posting is the most relevant but I'm afraid it doesn't lead *me* to an answer seeing as how new I am to this: [Xrm.Page.data is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357823/xrm-page-data-is-null)

My question is why does the console return this error if the element clearly exists?

Comment: So this is happening in code registered to the `OnLoad` event of the `OrderDetail` form?

Comment: The code that I'm running, I'm doing from the console after the whole page has loaded. The code that I intend to run is registered to run at OnLoad.

Comment: You'll find that this is the case generally throughout the CRM. Try running your code in any entity and you'll find similar behavior. However, if you put a breakpoint in your code and debug, you should see the correct behavior in the console during break mode. While in break mode, which line in particular breaks?

Comment: I took your suggestion and discovered two things: (1) I was focusing on the wrong line (the debugging helped me to see it was a line further down that was failing and not the one I initially thought) and (2) that I was using the wrong entity name. I was using "order" instead of "salesorder".

Comment: The Xrm.Page object lives in the context of a frame. If you want to use console in IE Dev tools without having to break in debug mode, you first have to point to the frame on the page. Example: frames[0].Xrm.Page.getAttribute('ati_clin').getValue()

Comment: Great. Thanks for the information! How should I conclude this question?

Comment: @Svendberg: Svendberg should probably make his comment an answer. I think it's better than mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A handy trick when debugging a problem like this:

The Xrm.Page object lives in the context of a frame. If you want to use console in IE Developer tools without having to break in debug mode, you first have to point to the frame on the page.

Example:

```
frames[0].Xrm.Page.getAttribute('ati_clin').getValue()
```